# samsung evo 840 500gb enable bitlocker without reinstall and with a password needed at each boot

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, bitlocker, fde

I was wondering if it is possible to turn on edrive + bitlocker on a Samsung Evo 840 SSD without reinstalling windows or messing with my windows install?

Comment: Your question is gather close votes because it is hard to understand. After reading it twice I think it is a valid question, but you might want to reword it and delete irrelevant parts. (e.g I do not care who you would want to protect the harddisk contents from. Just asking how to do this without wiping the existing installation and without significant performance inpact seems better than what you post right now).

Answer (score 1):

No you would have to reinstall so windows 8 can set this up on install, after you update the firmware on your SSD to support edrive

To be honest I would test the software version of bitlocker and see if there is any negative impact - I have it activated on all my windows machines and have never noticed it being slower.

For the software version no you wont need to re-install windows, just make sure bitlocker has finished encrypting before a reboot.

Bitlocker always asks for a password at boot to unlock the drive

Comment: Isn't this oly for the sw version? Perhaps I was unclear in op - I want the hw edrive version. And for that the only way known to me is ti wipe the drive install windows and turn on bittlocker. If everything went well the drive is encrypted in a few seconds and you aren't asked about encrypting only used or used + free space.

Comment: Ahh, right sorry wasn't clear, I will update my answer acordingly